# How to sort a list<string> by Dictionary<string, int>

Tags: c#, linq

I am implementing Data Mining Algorithm in .NET 4.0 (C#) and LINQ will work and I need some helps.

I have a List A and a Dictionary B. How to sort A by value B. For example `A = {b, d, c}` and `B = {(b,2),(c,5),(d,1),(e,3)}`. I need sort A -> `A = {c, b, d}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are asking for [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) or [OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916(v=vs.100).aspx) extensions:

```
List<string> A = ...
Dictionary<string, int> B = ...

A = A.OrderByDescending(a => B[a]).ToList()
```

Or using [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
A.Sort((x, y) => B[y].CompareTo(B[x]));
```

Comment: you mean `OrderByDescending`  i think

Comment: Upvoted for the addition,  the in-line `Sort` of `List<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
           List<string> A = new List<string>() {"b", "d", "c"};
            Dictionary<string,int> B = new Dictionary<string,int>() {{"b",2},{"c",5},{"d",1},{"e",3}};

            List<string> results = A.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { A = x, i = B[x] }).OrderByDescending(y => y.i).Select(z => z.A).ToList();
```